# Getting error code "string" from ArmNavigationErrorCodes for MoveArm action

Tags: ros, pr2-arm-navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The MoveArm action returns an  error_code in its result:

```
more MoveArmResult.msg
#An error code reflecting what went wrong
motion_planning_msgs/ArmNavigationErrorCodes error_code
```

which I can access then with:

```
result->error_code.val;
```

is there a way to get a string (which is more meaningful than an int) from this error code? something like the ENUM defined here:

/opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/motion_planning_common/motion_planning_msgs/msg/ArmNavigationErrorCodes.msg

```
# overall behavior
int32 PLANNING_FAILED=-1
int32 SUCCESS=1
int32 TIMED_OUT=-2

# start state errors
int32 START_STATE_IN_COLLISION=-3
int32 START_STATE_VIOLATES_PATH_CONSTRAINTS=-4
```

Thanks in advance,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9220/getting-error-code-%22string%22-from-armnavigationerrorcodes-for-movearm-action/) by [felix](https://answers.ros.org/users/154/felix/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2011-02-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are in unstable and using C++, there is a convenience function in motion_planning_msgs that does this for you:

```
#include <motion_planning_msgs/convert_messages.h>
```

....

std::string err_string = motion_planning_msgs::armNavigationErrorCodeToString(error_code);

....

---

Originally posted by [Sachin Chitta](https://answers.ros.org/users/39/sachin-chitta/) with karma: 1304 on 2011-02-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sachin Chitta](https://answers.ros.org/users/39/sachin-chitta/) on 2011-03-01**:
This will go into the release of the arm_navigation stacks against diamondback (which is essentially a copy of unstable).

**Comment by [felix](https://answers.ros.org/users/154/felix/) on 2011-02-28**:
Thanks. I guess I am not in unstable, it is not defined in my motion_planning_msgs/convert_messages.h . I am using the ubuntu virtual box appliance I grabbed from WG site a while ago (but I am up to date). Will this make it in the stable version sometime?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I realize this is old, but this Python one liner will give you a dict mapping error codes to error strings. I realize it's ugly and possibly not Pythonic, but it works (assuming all error strings are the only uppercase attributes of ArmNavigationErrorCodes).

```
dict((getattr(ArmNavigationErrorCodes, key), key) for key in filter(lambda x: x==x.upper(), dir(ArmNavigationErrorCodes)))
```

Figured someone else out there might be using Python with the arm_navigation stack.

---

Originally posted by [Ibrahim](https://answers.ros.org/users/331/ibrahim/) with karma: 307 on 2011-12-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1